# How do I switch users? Google Sign-in for websites

Tags: google-signin

I want to use google sign in for my app. Some workstations are shared between multiple users, so the ability to quickly change between users is important.

The sign in button seems to allow for this. ie if a user is "Signed In", clicking the sign in button presents the "Select account" dialog.

I can achieve this quick change functionality by simply having the button appear on every page.

The issue is however, that the "on success" event fires every time a page is loaded. This means I will be authenticating and creating sessions every time a page loads. This seems inefficient.

Is there an event that allows me to distinguish whether the user has expressly logged in vs google checking to see if the user is logged in?

Code is below as per docs. I've read the API docs and can't figure it out.

Thanks

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
  console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  alert('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
</script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="173138624956-ajom95asqea9p8f3ob0ntjvaalhf5r99.apps.googleusercontent.com">


<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using very basic declarative described flow [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#get_profile_information). This basically auto detects `class="g-signin2"`, renders the button and signs user in if possible - without any choice.

What you want can be achieved by using imperative flow which is described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic) (latter half is more important).
By using this approach, you can manually check if the user is signed-in and render the button if needed, let the user sign-in, or sign-out on demand.